# Bresser MikroCam SP 5.0 Does not have Driver for Anchor Chips (ID 0547:1236). Urgent!! Help Me

Tags: 18.04, drivers, webcam, camera, uvc

I have been assigned to use the **Bresser MikroCam SP 5.0 camera**. This camera is using **Anchor Chips Inc** with a **vendor ID of 0547**. I have tried to find a driver for allowing the chip to be recognized as a video input but it shows me a dead end. For now, the only way to communicate and streaming is through the provided software in windows. I am trying to use the camera with the ROS but first I need it to be recognized as a camera. Do you have any idea how can I resolve it? I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** and my kernel is **5.4.0-65-generic**. I also have tried using **cheese**, **gucview**, **camorama**, **AstroDMx** **Capture**, and **v4l2**.

Here is the output from `lsusb` :
[lsusb output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbhhK.png)

`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0547:1236 Anchor Chips, Inc.`

Here is the output from `dmesg` :
[dmesg output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/docuD.png)

```
[15285.634177] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[15285.790034] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=0547, idProduct=1236, bcdDevice= 0.02
[15285.790040] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[15285.790043] usb 1-9: Product: USB2.0 Camera
[15285.790045] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: TP
```

Here is the output from `usb-devices` :
[usb-devices output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJxye.png)

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=08 Cnt=03 Dev#=  9 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0547 ProdID=1236 Rev=00.02
S:  Manufacturer=TP
S:  Product=USB2.0 Camera
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

Comment: Please d not use pictures to show text include the text in the question.

Comment: @David I have included the text now. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

I use another camera brand (DLT-Cam PRO 5MP), but it seems to be the same device (dmesg, lsusb, usb-devices outputs bellow for comparison).
I was able to acquire images on a PC (Ubuntu 18.04) and use them with OpenCV using ToupTek SDK:
http://www.touptek.com/download/showdownload.php?lang=en&id=32

SDK includes API Manual. SDK's example "demosimplest" presents how to acquire image. The data array can be easily converted into OpenCV Mat type, e.g.:

```
HRESULT hr = Toupcam_PullImageV2(g_hcam, g_pImageData, 24, &info);
cv::Mat frameSource(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC3, g_pImageData);
```

And for camera type comparison:
dmesg output:

```
[ 1843.690558] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 1843.802470] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0547, idProduct=1236
[ 1843.802472] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1843.802473] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0 Camera
[ 1843.802474] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: TP
```

lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0547:1236 Anchor Chips, Inc.
```

usb-devices output:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  8 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0547 ProdID=1236 Rev=00.02
S:  Manufacturer=TP
S:  Product=USB2.0 Camera
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbfs
```